# How to create and submit a blogspot sitemap to google?

Tags: search, search-engine, blogspot

How to create and submit a blogspot sitemap to google?

Please show with an example...

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do that, Google owns blogger/blogspot and does that automatically.

But heres how: [link](http://theos.in/hakuna-matata/adding-google-sitemap-to-bloggercom-blog-account/)

Answer (score 0):

Jeet, you don't have to build a sitemap for blogspot as one is automatically built for you. Take, for example, my test blogspot blog's robots.txt file - http://brettmorgan-test-blawg.blogspot.com/robots.txt - you will see that a sitemap is already listed that lists all posts ordered by update date.